# How to make undo history interoperable between emacs and vim?

Tags: vim, emacs

Is it possible to share undo history of a file between emacs and vim?

I think it can be very useful: for example if your emacs config is broken and you want to quick edit files with vim to repair it.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible: As both editors are open source, the file formats of the undo information (assuming [undo-persistence](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/undo.txt.html#undo-persistence), stored in a separate file across editor invocations, not what is stored in memory during editing) is freely available; you'd "just" have to write a converter that translates the information. Some special features (thinking of Vim's undo *tree*, not sure if Emacs has something like that) may get lost, but a simple linear history should be common to *all* text editors.

However, I don't buy into your motivation for this: If my editor config is broken, I should not need a fancy editor and existing undo information to get it working again - the simplest text editor (think `gedit` or `nano`) should do. In fact, it is recommended to have backups of your important configuration - many people even use a fully-fledged revision control system (like *Git*) for this, and also publish their *dotfiles* on GitHub. You'd then only need version control, and no text editor at all, to get back running.

A better use case might be parallel editing of files - many people do share the same source code files in an IDE and Vim, to get the best of both worlds. Having undo shared and integrated would be nice there. However, as both Emacs and Vim are both very powerful text editors (and with that power have a steep learning curve and requiring a lot of time to master and tweak), I don't think there will be many people who are very proficient in both and continue to use both of them. Rather, I think most people will try out several editors, and sooner or later stay with a single one as their "main" editor.

Comment: Opinion not answer... My emacs multiple configs are hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/pietrodito/multi-emacs-flavors) but I don't want to revert back to last commit when I just need to comment a single line... And I do not want either to use an editor without vim keybindings as nano if I can. Moreover a quick edit with any editor will break my undo history tree....

Comment: You can ignore the opinion part if you don't like it; it's just food for thought :-) I think I do answer your question: Yes, it is possible, by writing a converter between the persisted undo histories.